# Data values need to store in CSV file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I cant stored data csv in file

I can Load the data but I cant stored the data in the CSV files and stored the file in the specific folder
My requirement was to load the web form details and send the email to specific users. I can able to download the csv file but I cant store the details in CSV file

```
    function webform_email_menu() {
        $items = array();
         $items['webform_email'] = array(
            'title'             =>  'Webform Email',  //page title
            'description'       =>  'Webform Information',  //description show when mouse hover on link
            'page callback'     =>  'webform_list',  //callback function which is invoked when menu item is called.
            'access callback'   =>  true,  //any user can access this page
           );
         return $items;
    }



function webform_list() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.export');
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.components');
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');  
    $submissions = webform_get_submissions(125);
echo "installation Type,Date of Purchase,Date of Install    ,Outdoor Unit Model,Outdoor Unit Serial,Indoor Unit 1 Model,Indoor Unit 1 Serial,Indoor Unit 2 Model,Indoor Unit 2 Serial,Indoor Unit 3 Model,Indoor Unit 3 Serial,Indoor Unit 4 Model,Indoor Unit 4 Serial,Indoor Unit 5 Model,Indoor Unit 5 Serial,Indoor Unit 6 Model,Indoor Unit 6 Serial,Indoor Unit 7 Model,Indoor Unit 7 Serial,Indoor Unit 8 Model,Indoor Unit 8 Serial,Indoor Unit 9 Model,Indoor Unit 9 Serial,Owner First Name,Owner Last Name,Installation Address 1,Installation Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country ,Owner Phone Number,Owner Email,Contractor Information,Contractor Name,Contractor Address 1 ,Contractor Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country,Contractor Phone Number,Contractor Email,Distributor Name,Distributor Address 1,Distributor Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country,TAC,Privacy Statement\n";
   $surveycomponents = db_select('webform_component')
     ->fields('webform_component')
     ->condition('nid', 125)
     ->orderBy('weight')
     ->orderBy('name')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllAssoc('cid', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count =0;
$i=2;
   foreach ($submissions as &$submission) {
       $submission_value=$submission->data;
       $i=0;
       foreach($submission_value as $submissionvalue){
            $numItems = count($submission_value);
            if(++$i === $numItems) {
                echo $csv_export="\n";
            }else{
                echo $csv_export=$submissionvalue[0].',';
            }
       }
    }

        $file_open = fopen('sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv', "a");
        file_put_contents("sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv", $csv_export);
    $csv_handler = fopen ('sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv','w');
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv_export);
    fclose ($csv_handler);

}
```

where I did mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in CSV file using an array like this

```
$data = [[1,2,3][11,22,33]];
$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($data as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder permissions in which you are trying to store/save your file. i.e. sites/default/files/csv. Folder should be writable in order to write/add file into it. In terminal you can use below command to give proper permissions to the folder:

`chmod 775 -R /sites/default/files/csv`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about you are expected but you need to use drupal functions to get righet path to use and prepare it be modified :

```
$path = drupal_realpath('public://').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'csv';
file_prepare_directory($path);
$file_open = fopen($path.'/csvfile.csv', "a");
file_put_contents($path.'/csvfile.csv', $csv_export);
```

[...]

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_prepare_directory/7.x

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/drupal_realpath/7.x